# Style a vertical li navigation menu with each li having an image and text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-lists, nav

I'm working on a project and I've got a problem where I can't think of how to style my vertical navigation properly. I want it to be covering the whole height and look the following way (vertical from up to down): DIV element for logo with the same height as the list items and no margin, navigation list items with image in the middle and text beneath them, with a little margin on top and bottom. 
Here's my current code -

HTML:

```
    <div className="Dashboard">
    <nav className="SideBox">
        <img className="SideLogo" src={Logo}></img>
        <ul>
            <li><img src={Logo}/><p>Accounts</p></li>
            <li><img src={Logo}/><p>Transactions</p></li>
            <li><img src={Logo}/><p>Documents</p></li>
            <li><img src={Logo}/><p>Wallet</p></li>
            <li><img src={Logo}/><p>Calendar</p></li>
            <li><img src={Logo}/><p>Settings</p></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Dashboard {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.Dashboard * {
    width: 150px;
    height: calc(100vh / 7);
    background-color: blue;

}

.SideLogo {
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    display: block;
}

.Dashboard ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
}

.Dashboard li {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;

}

.Dashboard img {
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: could you post an example image, I would love to help, but can't understand your description...

Comment: Sure ! I'm aiming for this https://imgur.com/rTpJS2z

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you a lot
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_mobile_navbar
If you just want a vertical menu... The only you have to add is an `<img>` tag with appropriate image

BTW, you shouldn't repeat your code which has the same values such as margin and padding in different classes

Comment: Thanks ! This does help, but I needed some extra help with how to cover the height of the full screen with that vertical bar and especially with how to position the img appropriately like here  imgur.com/rTpJS2z